# Hyperledger Fabric + NodeJS app - Query but no Invoke

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Here's an interesting situation...

I've deployed a Fabric network over two machines and I'm able to query and invoke transactions through cli.

I'm also using a NodeJS app with which I can query the network but can't invoke any transaction.

This error appears whenever I invoke from the NodeJS app:

```
"Failed to connect before the deadline".
```

The logs from the node app:

```
[Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
error: [Orderer.js]: Orderer grpcs://orderer.test.com:7050 has an error Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
```

This is the template NodeJS app I'm using: https://github.com/olegabu/fabric-starter-rest

Any ideea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So your SDK is running inside a container ? 
Have you try to curl the orderer inside the SDK container ?

If it's not working maybe you can add host of your orderer when you run the container (or inside the dockerfile)

```
--add-host=orderer.test.com:${orderer-ip}
```

Comment: My NodeJS app is not running inside a docker container. I'm cloning the repo inside the project folder and run the app from there. The odd thing is that I can query the network but not invoke...

Comment: Host1: orderer, 2 peers, cli; Host2: 2 peers. The network works, I can query and invoke from the cli.

Comment: I tried running them in both hosts, but not in a docker container

Comment: On the host of the nodeJS app, have  you try add in /etc/hosts the hostname orderer.test.com with his IP ?

Comment: I'm connecting the hosts with swarm, they are communicating. I'm able to invoke from any of the hosts though the cli container. The issue is with the NodeJS app. Now I've tried adding the NodeJS app inside a docker container ... when I try to curl port ... the request just hangs and never gets anything... https://github.com/olegabu/fabric-starter-rest